# How to find the index of control in datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

As datalist controls are repeated how can i get the index of each of asp button `btnExplodedGroupCode` and also of telerik radcomboBox in datalist(note) `RadCmbExplodedGroupCodes`

```
  <asp:DataList ID="dlExplodedGroupCodes" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        RepeatColumns="1" CellSpacing="4" CellPadding="4">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnExplodedGroupCode" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProcedureGroupId") %>'
                Text='<%# Eval("MainGroup") %>' Width="75px" OnClientClick="return CheckToochSelection();"
                OnClick="btnExplodedGroupCode_Click" CssClass="rg_button" />
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadCmbExplodedGroupCodes" runat="server" DataValueField="ProcedureID"
                DataTextField="ProcedureName" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" AllowCustomText="false"
                AutoPostBack="true" Skin="MyBlueSkin" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Height="200px"
                Width="19px" DropDownWidth="298px" NoWrap="true" >
          </telerik:RadComboBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: You want this on client side or server side?

Comment: I want it on client side

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

Let me know if i am not understood your question.

**Client Side:**

JS

```
function CheckToochSelection(a) {
            alert(a);
        }
```

ASPX

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnExplodedGroupCode" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>'
            Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Width="75px" OnClientClick='<%# "return CheckToochSelection(" + Container.ItemIndex +");" %>'
            CssClass="rg_button"  OnClick="btnExplodedGroupCode_Click"/>
```

**Server Side:**

```
protected void btnExplodedGroupCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = ((sender as Button).NamingContainer as DataListItem).ItemIndex;
}
```

Comment: i want index of controls

Comment: Can you please elaborate your scenario? Which result you want?

Comment: Am using datalist with repeat column,column containing asp button and telerik radcombobox.i what the index of that column .So than when i click on column what to give an alert.